# Static asset manager for Java webapps

Tags: java, web-applications, deployment, spring-mvc

Not a Java guy here, so forgive me if this is something trivial.

Most modern web application frameworks support some sort of asset manager that allows for easy script or stylesheet inclusion and also commonly supports the notion of bundling and minification.

Are there any such libraries for Java based webapps?  I am using Spring 3.x

Right now, we just have a build script that has hardcoded lists of assets that should be bundled together and in our code we have something like (pseudo code):

```
if (production) {
   <script src="bundle1.js">
} else {
   <script src="file1.js">
   <script src="file2.js">
   <script src="file3.js">
}
```

This is much less than ideal - who wants to update a hard coded list?

Comment: Assetic does this for Symfony2, I am also trying to find an answer for this in Spring

Answer (score 0):

Seems like **[Jenkins](http://jenkins-ci.org/)** can help you. it is easy to use and very intuitive.

It is an open source continuous integration tool written in Java.

Jenkins provides continuous integration services for software development, primarily in the Java programming language. It is a server-based system running in a servlet container such as Apache Tomcat. It supports SCM tools including CVS, Subversion, Git, Mercurial, Perforce and Clearcase, and ***can execute Apache Ant and Apache Maven based projects as well as arbitrary shell scripts and Windows batch commands.***

Builds can be started by various means, including being triggered by commit in a version control system, scheduling via a cron-like mechanism, building when other builds have completed, and by requesting a specific build URL.

Edit:

[jwar](http://jawr.java.net/) might suit you. it allows you to minimize javascript and css and has [spring integration](http://jawr.java.net/integration/spring.html).

Hope this helps

Comment: We use Jenkins to build the app and execute our build script already.  This doesn't solve the problem.  What I am looking for is something that does the bundling and minification from within the app.  Rails, ASP.NET MVC, Node.js, Python all have these things.  Im sure something like this exists for Java - I just havent found it.

Comment: @BryanMigliorisi Edited answer. Hope jwar was more in the lines of what you need.

Comment: @BryanMigliorisi, it was not answer or what? could you configure JAWR with your Spring project?